# bs4 won't open locally stored html page correctly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I attempt to parse a locally stored copy of a webpage, beautifulsoup returns gibberish to me. I don't understand why as I've never faced this problem when using the requests and bs4 modules together for scraping tasks.

here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import os

url_2 = r'/Users/davidferreira/Documents/coding_2/ak_screen_scraping/bmra/'


os.chdir(url_2)
f = open('re_2.html')
soup = BS(url_2, "lxml")
f.close()

print soup
```

this code returns the following :

```
<html><body><p>/Users/davidferreira/Documents/coding_2/ak_screen_scraping/bmra/</p></body></html>
```

I wasn't able to find a similar problem online so I've posted it here. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the path (which you named `url_2`) to `BeautifulSoup` so it treats that as a web page text and returns it, neatly wrapped in some minimal HTML. Seems fine.

Try constructing the BS from the file's contents instead. See here how it works: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup

```
soup = BS(f)
```

should do...